# Namedtuple in Numpy

Tags: python, oop, numpy, namedtuple

I really like the functionally of the namedtuple collection. Specifically I like how useful it is for points in 2-dimensional space.

```
In : from collections import namedtuple

In : Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

In : p = Point(1,2)

In : p.x
Out: 1

In : p.y
Out: 2
```

I think that's a lot clearer than referring to the first and second entries of a list. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so that Point is also a numpy array. For example

```
 In: p1 = Point(1,2)
 In: p2 = Point(3,4)
 In: (p1+p2).x 
 Out: 4
```

And similar nice functionality from numpy. In other words I think I want Point to be a subclass of numpy? Can I do this? And how?

Comment: `np.recarray` are structured arrays that let you access fields as attributes - sort of the namedtuple equivalent.  But you can't readily perform 2d math on structured arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A structured array like `point_type` does not define math operations that involve several fields.

With the sample from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455682/901925

```
In [470]: point_type = [('x', float), ('y', float)]
In [471]: points = np.array([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)], dtype=point_type)
In [472]: points
Out[472]: 
array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
In [473]: points[0]+points[1]
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.void' and 'numpy.void'
```

Instead I can create a 2d array, and then view it as `point_type` - the databuffer layout will be the same:

```
In [479]: points = np.array([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)],float)
In [480]: points
Out[480]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])
In [481]: points.view(point_type)
Out[481]: 
array([[(1.0, 2.0)],
       [(3.0, 4.0)],
       [(5.0, 6.0)]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
In [482]: points.view(point_type).view(np.recarray).x
Out[482]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 5.]])
```

I can do math across rows, and continue to view the results as points:

```
In [483]: (points[0]+points[1]).view(point_type).view(np.recarray)
Out[483]: 
rec.array([(4.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
In [484]: _.x
Out[484]: array([ 4.])
In [485]: points.sum(0).view(point_type)
Out[485]: 
array([(9.0, 12.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Alternatively I could start with the `point_type`, and view it as 2d for the math, and then view-it-back

```
pdt1=np.dtype((float, (2,)))
In [502]: points
Out[502]: 
array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
In [503]: points.view(pdt1)
Out[503]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])
In [504]: points.view(pdt1).sum(0).view(point_type)
Out[504]: 
array([(9.0, 12.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

So it is possible to view and operate on an array as 2d and as recarray.  To be pretty or useful it probably needs to be burried in a user defined class.

Another option to crib ideas from the `recarray` class.  At its core it is just a structured array with a specialized `__getattribute__` (and setattribute) method.  That method first trys the normal array methods and attributes (e.g. `x.shape`, `x.sum`).  Then it tries to fine `attr` in the defined fieldnames.

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    try:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    except AttributeError: # attr must be a fieldname
        pass
    fielddict = ndarray.__getattribute__(self, 'dtype').fields
    try:
        res = fielddict[attr][:2]
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        raise AttributeError("record array has no attribute %s" % attr)
    return self.getfield(*res)
    ...
```

`points.view(np.recarray).x` becomes `points.getfield(*points.dtype.fields['x'])`.

An alternate approach would be to borrow from `namedtuple` (`/usr/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py`), and define `x` and `y` properties, which would index the `[:,0]` and `[:,1]` columns of the 2d array.
  It may be easiest to add those properties to a subclass of `np.matrix`, letting that class ensure that most math results are 2d.

Answer (score 2):

You can get somewhat similar functionality using numpy's [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
In [36]: import numpy as np
    ...: point_type = [('x', float), ('y', float)]
    ...: points = np.array([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)], dtype=point_type)

In [37]: points[2]
Out[37]: (5.0, 6.0)

In [38]: points['x']
Out[38]: array([ 1.,  3.,  5.])
```

It is even possible to make the all the fields available using atribute access (e.g. using `points.x`) by converting the structure array to a [recarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html):

```
In [39]: pts = points.view(np.recarray)

In [40]: pts['x']
Out[40]: array([ 1.,  3.,  5.])

In [41]: pts.x
Out[41]: array([ 1.,  3.,  5.])

In [42]: pts[2]
Out[42]: (5.0, 6.0)
```

Note that recarray apparently has some performance problems, and can be a bit annoying to use. You might also want to look into the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which also allows accessing fields by attribute, and which does not have the problems of recarray.